# Angular error Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: html, jquery, angular, import, components

[image]

I import some js files to my component but when i start app the browser gives me this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.
I load jquery before everything else so I don't understand how it can give error.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to install jquery using npm, and also don't forget to add it to the index.html file, I have shown it in the photo. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIZL6.png)